# EpiServer 7 : Category tab not appearing

Tags: episerver

In EpiServer 7 CMS editor, I have added multiple categories.
I have 2 issues then
1. Those are not coming up in code in CategoryList.
2. Category tab is not appearing in any of the pages
Should I be adding property to my pagebase like below to make it work?

```
    [Display(Name = "Categories", GroupName = PropertyGroupNames.Categories, Order = 2011)]
     public virtual CategoryList Categories { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add your own "Categories" to your page model. The categories are now stored within the PageData so you can basicly reach them by using

CurrentPage.GetProperty("PageCategory")

If you are at editmode in a page, you can reach your categories by clicking on "settings" and you will see them there in a selectbox. They do not look anything like they did in episerver 6 or earlier.

Make sure that you have created your categories by going to adminmode->config->edit categories. There you'll see your categories.

Answer (score 0):

Categories are not in a separate tab anymore.

The new category picker is normally first on the content tab.

You don't need to define it in code.

Comment: ok,do you mean to use the "Category selection" property? But even after using this in a page, I do not get the category list in CategoryList enumerable.

Comment: I'm talking about the built-in property on PageData, named Category. Can you post some code on how you are trying to access the data?